# Changing Order of Summations

Tags: probability

I was looking at solutions to a problem I was working on for Stats and Probability. And in the solution, I saw the following equality being used:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{i=k}^\infty p_{X}(i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^i p_{X}(i)$$

Where $p_{X}$ is the PMF for the random variable, $X$, and the numberical values of $X$ are represented by $i$.

Is this equality true by symmetry?

What I mean is:
The right (inner) summation of the left-side of the equality is "large" for small values of $k$, and "small" for large values of $k$. Is this mirrored by the "large" values of the right (inner) summation of the right-side of the equality for large values of $i$, and "small" values for small values of $i$?

In simpler terms, do the right (inner) summations (on both sides of the equality) even out as the outer summations go from $1$ --> $\infty$?

Comment: Hint: sum the function $p_X(i)1_{k \leq i}$ over the whole space and use Tonelli's Theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u(j)$ be defined as

$$
u(j)=\begin{cases}
1&,j\ge 0\\\\
0&,j<0
\end{cases}$$

If $a_{ik}\ge 0$ (this is a sufficient but not a necessary condition), then we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{i=k}^\infty a_{ik}&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ik}u(i-k)\\\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{ik}u(i-k) \,\,\dots\text{by Fubini's Theorem}\\\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^i a_{ik}
\end{align}$$

By letting $a_{ik}=p_X(i)\ge 0$, we find that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{i=k}^\infty p_X(i)= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^i p_X(i)$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Very clear, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You are summing over all integer values of $i,k$ where $1\leq k\leq i$.   As long as the series converges then:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{i=k}^\infty \text{blagh} ~&=~ \mathop{\sum\qquad}_{(i,k)\in\Bbb N^2~:~1\leq k\leq i} \text{blagh} \\ & = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^i \text{blagh}\end{align}$$

That is all.